# получение ip пользователя через отправленный им GET запрос

Tags: javascript, php, get, ip

Есть некое веб-приложение, в котором от пользователя уходит на сервер гет запрос к БД, можно ли на стороне сервера считать ip пользователя через этот запрос, и если можно то как?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно, обращайтесь к документации вашего сервера

Comment: Если сервер PHP, то `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.